# WPF DataGrid - Triggers for Conditional Formatting on Individual Cells

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid, styles

I need to get the cells in my DataGrid reflect conditional rules... I have gotten so far and having already spent too much time on this I am hopeful someone can help me out? so, this is how my grid currently looks when run:

[image]

Here you can see (ignoring the **Outcome** & **Criterion** columns) that there are three sets of two columns to be concerned with here. I am currently applying the conditional rule to the **XPercVerified** columns but ultimately I want the **EF[X]** columns to show the background changes based on the values in the respective PercVerified column. Another point to make is that there can be any number of these Two-column-Combinations...

The problem I currently have however is that I only seem to be able to apply the rule to conditionally format the entire Row. In the screenshot above you can see that the column **1PercVerified** has a 1 in the first row.. This makes the entire row green. The code is as follows:

```
Private Sub dgUnitMatrix_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs) Handles dgUnitMatrix.AutoGeneratingColumn

    If (e.Column.Header.ToString().Contains("PercVerified")) Then

        e.Column.CellStyle = TryCast(Application.Current.FindResource("PercVerified"), Style)

    End If

End Sub
```

Here we are calling the **AutoGeneratingColumn** event and when we have a column that is *like* **PercVerified**, call the Application Resource Style:

```
<Application x:Class="Application"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
ShutdownMode="OnMainWindowClose">

    <Application.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 1PercVerified}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2.0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding 1PercVerified}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2.0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Which exists in the **Application.XAML** file.
The other issue I appear to have is that even if I can get the above to work on just the cell (instead of the row) - I only appear to be able to be definitive in my conditions (i.e. bound value must equal - I cant do where integer is greater than or less than?)... Is this true?

I have started to look further afield as I am getting the impression that this styling is not going to work for what I want... So, IValueConverters have cropped up a few times but I just dont seem to be able to get this working. Is it worth me spending the time looking into these only to find out it is another dead end??

I can supply any extra info anyone might need... I am desperate to get this sorted as I have already wasted too much time on something in WPF that is just SOOO MUCH EASIER in Winforms!

**Edit**

Following the excellent answer from J.H. I have adapted it to wor with the DataRowView that is passed as the object value (instead of the examples Class Object).

In the converter, we are creating the variable dc. That entire block of code has been changed to:

```
    ' Get the cells DataContext as our data class '
    Dim dc As DataRowView
    dc = TryCast(cell.DataContext, DataRowView)
    If IsNothing(dc) Then Exit Function

    ' Get the column number of the columnName that matches the Path 
    Dim ColNo As Integer
    Dim idx As Integer = 0
    For Each column As DataColumn In dc.DataView.Table.Columns
        If column.ColumnName = path Then
            ColNo = idx
        End If
        idx = idx + 1
    Next
```

then when doing the comparison for the conditional formatting instead of:

```
Dim pv = dc.GetType().GetProperty(path).GetValue(dc)
```

we use

```
Dim pv As String = dc.Row.Item(ColNo).ToString()
```

Apart from a few other changes due to variances this works a treat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a IValueConverter. You'd need to pass in the DataGridCell to the converter. From the cell you can get the datacontext and the binding for the cell. Once you have those, some reflection can get you the value of the PercVerifiedX field. You can detect the EFX field and then get the appropriate PercVerifiedX field that goes with it.

Here is some code, note that my property names aren't quite like yours (can't start a property with a number) so you may have to adjust the code some. Also, I could've used numbers but chose strings for the DataTrigger.Value just to show that it's not the PercVerified value but the converter's return value.
And, I mixed it up a bit - red for 0 percs, green for 1-3 percs and purple for 4+ percs. See the xaml and the converter's code.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication16"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PercVerifiedConverter x:Key="PercVerifiedConverter" />
        <Style x:Key="PercVerified" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Red">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkRed"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2.0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Green">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2.0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource PercVerifiedConverter}}" Value="Purple">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2.0"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn" />
</Window>
```

.VB (what a PITA with the comment 's to get the color coding right)

```
Imports System.Globalization

Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the designer. '
        InitializeComponent()

        Dim vm As New VM
        vm.Data = New List(Of MyData) From {
                New MyData() With {.Outcome = "Outcome 1", .Criterion = "1.1", .PercVerified1 = 1, .EF1 = "EP, ECH", .PercVerified3 = 0, .EF3 = "", .PercVerified4 = 0, .EF4 = "EWT"},
                New MyData() With {.Outcome = "", .Criterion = "1.2", .PercVerified1 = 0, .EF1 = "", .PercVerified3 = 1, .EF3 = "O, EP", .PercVerified4 = 0, .EF4 = ""},
                New MyData() With {.Outcome = "", .Criterion = "1.3", .PercVerified1 = 0, .EF1 = "", .PercVerified3 = 0, .EF3 = "O, EP", .PercVerified4 = 4, .EF4 = ""}
            }
        Me.DataContext = vm
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(sender As Object, e As DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs)
        If (e.Column.Header.ToString().Contains("PercVerified") Or e.Column.Header.ToString().Contains("EF")) Then
            e.Column.CellStyle = TryCast(Me.FindResource("PercVerified"), Style)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class MyData
    Public Property Outcome As String
    Public Property Criterion As String
    Public Property PercVerified1 As String
    Public Property EF1 As String
    Public Property PercVerified3 As String
    Public Property EF3 As String
    Public Property PercVerified4 As String
    Public Property EF4 As String
End Class

Public Class VM
    Public Property Data As List(Of MyData)
End Class

Public Class PercVerifiedConverter
    Implements IValueConverter

    Public Function Convert(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Convert = Nothing
        Dim cell As DataGridCell
        Dim dc As MyData

        ' Get the DataGridCell passed in '
        cell = TryCast(value, DataGridCell)
        If IsNothing(cell) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the cells DataContext as our data class '
        dc = TryCast(cell.DataContext, MyData)
        If IsNothing(dc) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the cells column - need it for the binding '
        Dim tc As DataGridTextColumn ' Assuming your cells are DataGridTextColumns '
        tc = TryCast(cell.Column, DataGridTextColumn)
        If IsNothing(tc) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the columns binding '
        Dim b As Binding
        b = TryCast(tc.Binding, System.Windows.Data.Binding)
        If IsNothing(b) Then Exit Function

        ' Get the path off the binding '
        Dim path As String
        path = b.Path.Path ' Name of the property this column is bound to - PercVerified1, EF1, etc... '

        ' If one of the "EF" properties, convert path to the appropriate "PercVerified" path '
        If path.Contains("EF") Then
            Dim pvNum = path.Replace("EF", String.Empty) ' EF1 becomes 1 '
            path = "PercVerified" + pvNum ' path is now PercVerified1 '
        End If
        If path.Contains("PercVerified") Then
            Dim pv = dc.GetType().GetProperty(path).GetValue(dc)
            If pv = 0 Then
                Convert = "Red"
            ElseIf pv >= 1 And pv <= 3 Then
                Convert = "Green"
            ElseIf pv >= 4 Then
                Convert = "Purple"
            End If
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(value As Object, targetType As Type, parameter As Object, culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        Throw New NotImplementedException()
    End Function
End Class
```

And, a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, it is totally put me in the direction I was looking for. I think I have my head around this now. I do have a bit of work to do with this though as the 'value' being passed into the converter on yours is the instance of MyData object (with Properties that you use).. For mine I am getting (I think??) a DataRow which has the columns and the row.. .so I will need to do something there. I will update!

Comment: Correction - my DataContext for value is actually a DataRowView. I am hoping I can do something with this that replicates getting the pv value.

Comment: Managed to get this customized to work with a DataRowView being passed as a value instead of the MyData object. I will post my change in an edit of the original question. Many thanks agani J.H.

Comment: @ChrisHill - You must be using a DataTable. Glad you were able to modify it to work for you. One suggestion though, you don't need to get the column's index. You can just use the 'path' variable to index into dc. Like this: Dim pv as String = dc(path).ToString()

Comment: Ahh I had wondered about that in a fleeting thought... Brilliant! Thanks again! I am just looking at some gradient functionality I can use now to make the cell backgrounds like a little nicer than the flat bold colors!